# Mostrar mas de un dato en un item de un Listview

Tags: android, mysql, listview

Necesito mostrar 3 campos de un tabla de una **BD** dentro de un **item** en un `Listview`, lo que tengo hasta el momento es que muestra los datos pero en diferentes **items**. ¿ alguna idea de como incluir todo en un solo item ?

```
 jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject preguntaDatos = null;
                    try {
                        preguntaDatos = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String pregunta = null;
                    String respuesta= null;
                    String comentario=null;
                    try {
                        assert preguntaDatos != null;
                        pregunta = preguntaDatos.getString("pregunta");
                        respuesta = preguntaDatos.getString("respuesta");
                        comentario = preguntaDatos.getString("comentario");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    preguntas.add(pregunta);
                    preguntas.add(respuesta);
                    preguntas.add(comentario);
                }
```

resultado esperado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes agregar los datos en una sola variable y separarlos por un salto de línea, ve si mi respuesta te ayuda, por cierto no se porque te dan -1 =|.

Comment: La verdad deberían explicar el porque de cada -1 pero en fin, gracias por el tiempo !

Comment: Me parece más sencilla y rápida la respuesta de @Elenasys :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK me parece que entiendo quieres los datos en un solo elemento, puedes definir una variable tipo String en donde guardarías los 3 datos, para posteriormente agregarlos al List preguntas:

```
String pregrespcomment;

 try {
                        assert preguntaDatos != null;
                   pregrespcomment = preguntaDatos.getString("pregunta") + "\n" + preguntaDatos.getString("respuesta") + "\n" + preguntaDatos.getString("comentario");
                        /*pregunta = preguntaDatos.getString("pregunta");
                        respuesta = preguntaDatos.getString("respuesta");
                        comentario = preguntaDatos.getString("comentario");*/
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    preguntas.add(pregrespcomment);
                    /*preguntas.add(pregunta);
                    preguntas.add(respuesta);
                    preguntas.add(comentario);*/
```

---

Lo que propongo es agregar los datos a una sola variable:

```
  pregrespcomment = preguntaDatos.getString("pregunta") + "\n" + preguntaDatos.getString("respuesta") + "\n" + preguntaDatos.getString("comentario");
```

y posteriormente agregarlo al list, para poder mostrarlo en tu `ListView`.

```
preguntas.add(pregrespcomment);
```

Comment: Ah funcionado todo bien, gracias. Como siempre ayudando ...

Comment: Hola Elenasys necesito de su ayuda

Comment: @HugoRodriguez hola que tal que sucede.

Comment: @Elenasys Disculpa lo que pasa es que quiero saber si es que se pude hacer alguna funcion para alinear String al centro,left o rigth?

Comment: ahh hola haha , en un TextView mmm puedes usar la gravedad por ejemplo: android:layout_gravity="center" para centro , android:layout_gravity="left" para izquierda  o android:layout_gravity="right" para derecha.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es usar `CustomListViews`.

Por ejemplo, crearías un *xml* que se llame `custom_item.xml` el cual le colocas 3 *TextViews* para almacenar los datos de los 3 campos que necesitas y sería mas o menos así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <TextView android:id="@+id/campo1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/campo2" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/campo3" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

En cuanto al método `getView();` de tu *adapter* solo inflas tu *xml* creado y lo demás es lo mismo:

```
   convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_item, null);
```

Para ver todo el tutorial completo visita este [enlace](https://web.archive.org/web/20200928225021/http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx).

Comment: Creo que me explique mal jaja necestio traer los datos de una tabla, y esta tabla contiene tres columnas y necesito las 3 columnas en un solo item ... añadire a la pregunta el resultado que busco

Comment: @FelixBeeb Pues si, eso hace lo que te respondí. creas un xml con los 3 campos(Por eso tiene _textViews_ llamados 'campo1', 'campo2', 'campo3'), entonces, si inflas ese xml en tu adapter va a sustituir al item comun y corriente. Ya después ya puedes pasarle tus datos de tu BD.

Comment: Bueno esto también podría ser otra solución aunque se tendría que modificar el layout del elemento en un ListView, pero es valida.